# Opensips 1.11 + RTPproxy 1.2.1 integration in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: voip, ubuntu-14.04, opensips

I have configure opensips server with rtpproxy in a 32 bit ubuntu server .
My config file is given below

```
#
# $Id$
#
# OpenSIPS residential configuration script
#     by OpenSIPS Solutions <team@opensips-solutions.com>
#
# This script was generated via "make menuconfig", from
#   the "Residential" scenario.
# You can enable / disable more features / functionalities by
#   re-generating the scenario with different options.#
#
# Please refer to the Core CookBook at:
#      http://www.opensips.org/Resources/DocsCookbooks
# for a explanation of possible statements, functions and parameters.
#


####### Global Parameters #########

debug=3
log_stderror=yes
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0



fork=yes
children=4

mhomed=yes
/* uncomment the following lines to enable debugging */
#debug=6
#fork=no
#log_stderror=yes

/* uncomment the next line to enable the auto temporary blacklisting of 
   not available destinations (default disabled) */
#disable_dns_blacklist=no

/* uncomment the next line to enable IPv6 lookup after IPv4 dns 
   lookup failures (default disabled) */
#dns_try_ipv6=yes

/* comment the next line to enable the auto discovery of local aliases
   based on revers DNS on IPs */
auto_aliases=no


listen=udp:public ip:5060   # CUSTOMIZE ME


disable_tcp=yes

disable_tls=yes


####### Modules Section ########

#set module path
mpath="/usr/local/lib/opensips/modules/"

#### SIGNALING module
loadmodule "signaling.so"

#### StateLess module
loadmodule "sl.so"

#### Transaction Module
loadmodule "tm.so"
modparam("tm", "fr_timeout", 5)
modparam("tm", "fr_inv_timeout", 30)
modparam("tm", "restart_fr_on_each_reply", 0)
modparam("tm", "onreply_avp_mode", 1)

#### Record Route Module
loadmodule "rr.so"
/* do not append from tag to the RR (no need for this script) */
modparam("rr", "append_fromtag", 0)

#### MAX ForWarD module
loadmodule "maxfwd.so"

#### SIP MSG OPerationS module
loadmodule "sipmsgops.so"

#### FIFO Management Interface
loadmodule "mi_fifo.so"
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_name", "/tmp/opensips_fifo")
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_mode", 0666)


#### URI module
loadmodule "uri.so"
modparam("uri", "use_uri_table", 0)











#### USeR LOCation module
loadmodule "usrloc.so"
modparam("usrloc", "nat_bflag", "NAT")
modparam("usrloc", "db_mode",   0)

#### REGISTRAR module
loadmodule "registrar.so"
modparam("registrar", "tcp_persistent_flag", "TCP_PERSISTENT")
modparam("registrar", "received_avp", "$avp(received_nh)")
/* uncomment the next line not to allow more than 10 contacts per AOR */
#modparam("registrar", "max_contacts", 10)

#### ACCounting module
loadmodule "acc.so"
/* what special events should be accounted ? */
modparam("acc", "early_media", 0)
modparam("acc", "report_cancels", 0)
/* by default we do not adjust the direct of the sequential requests.
   if you enable this parameter, be sure the enable "append_fromtag"
   in "rr" module */
modparam("acc", "detect_direction", 0)
modparam("acc", "failed_transaction_flag", "ACC_FAILED")
/* account triggers (flags) */
modparam("acc", "log_flag", "ACC_DO")
modparam("acc", "log_missed_flag", "ACC_MISSED")












####  NAT modules
loadmodule "nathelper.so"
modparam("nathelper", "natping_interval", 10)
modparam("nathelper", "ping_nated_only", 1)
modparam("nathelper", "received_avp", "$avp(received_nh)")

loadmodule "rtpproxy.so"
modparam("rtpproxy", "rtpproxy_sock", "udp:localhost:7890") # CUSTOMIZE ME
modparam("nathelper", "force_socket", "udp:localhost:7890")







####### Routing Logic ########

# main request routing logic

route{
    force_rport();
    if (nat_uac_test("23")) {
        if (is_method("REGISTER")) {
            fix_nated_register();
            setbflag(NAT);
        } else {
            fix_nated_contact();
            setflag(NAT);
        }
    }


    if (!mf_process_maxfwd_header("10")) {
        sl_send_reply("483","Too Many Hops");
        exit;
    }

    if (has_totag()) {
        # sequential request withing a dialog should
        # take the path determined by record-routing
        if (loose_route()) {

            if (is_method("BYE")) {
                setflag(ACC_DO); # do accounting ...
                setflag(ACC_FAILED); # ... even if the transaction fails
            } else if (is_method("INVITE")) {
                # even if in most of the cases is useless, do RR for
                # re-INVITEs alos, as some buggy clients do change route set
                # during the dialog.
                record_route();
            }

            if (check_route_param("nat=yes")) 
                setflag(NAT);

            # route it out to whatever destination was set by loose_route()
            # in $du (destination URI).
            route(relay);
        } else {

            if ( is_method("ACK") ) {
                if ( t_check_trans() ) {
                    # non loose-route, but stateful ACK; must be an ACK after 
                    # a 487 or e.g. 404 from upstream server
                    t_relay();
                    exit;
                } else {
                    # ACK without matching transaction ->
                    # ignore and discard
                    exit;
                }
            }
            sl_send_reply("404","Not here");
        }
        exit;
    }

    # CANCEL processing
    if (is_method("CANCEL"))
    {
        if (t_check_trans())
            t_relay();
        exit;
    }

    t_check_trans();

    if ( !(is_method("REGISTER")  ) ) {

        if (from_uri==myself)

        {

        } else {
            # if caller is not local, then called number must be local

            if (!uri==myself) {
                send_reply("403","Rely forbidden");
                exit;
            }
        }

    }

    # preloaded route checking
    if (loose_route()) {
        xlog("L_ERR",
        "Attempt to route with preloaded Route's [$fu/$tu/$ru/$ci]");
        if (!is_method("ACK"))
            sl_send_reply("403","Preload Route denied");
        exit;
    }

    # record routing
    if (!is_method("REGISTER|MESSAGE"))
        record_route();

    # account only INVITEs
    if (is_method("INVITE")) {

        setflag(ACC_DO); # do accounting
    }


    if (!uri==myself) {
        append_hf("P-hint: outbound\r\n"); 

        route(relay);
    }

    # requests for my domain

    if (is_method("PUBLISH|SUBSCRIBE"))
    {
        sl_send_reply("503", "Service Unavailable");
        exit;
    }

    if (is_method("REGISTER"))
    {


        if (   0 ) setflag(TCP_PERSISTENT);

        if (!save("location"))
            sl_reply_error();

        exit;
    }

    if ($rU==NULL) {
        # request with no Username in RURI
        sl_send_reply("484","Address Incomplete");
        exit;
    }







    # do lookup with method filtering
    if (!lookup("location","m")) {


        t_newtran();
        t_reply("404", "Not Found");
        exit;
    } 

    if (isbflagset(NAT)) setflag(NAT);

    # when routing via usrloc, log the missed calls also
    setflag(ACC_MISSED);
    route(relay);
}


route[relay] {
    # for INVITEs enable some additional helper routes
    if (is_method("INVITE")) {

        if (isflagset(NAT)) {
            rtpproxy_offer("ro");
        }

        t_on_branch("per_branch_ops");
        t_on_reply("handle_nat");
        t_on_failure("missed_call");
    }

    if (isflagset(NAT)) {
        add_rr_param(";nat=yes");
        }

    if (!t_relay()) {
        send_reply("500","Internal Error");
    };
    exit;
}




branch_route[per_branch_ops] {
    xlog("new branch at $ru\n");
}


onreply_route[handle_nat] {
    if (nat_uac_test("1"))
        fix_nated_contact();
    if ( isflagset(NAT) )
        rtpproxy_answer("ro");
    xlog("incoming reply\n");
}


failure_route[missed_call] {
    if (t_was_cancelled()) {
        exit;
    }

    # uncomment the following lines if you want to block client 
    # redirect based on 3xx replies.
    ##if (t_check_status("3[0-9][0-9]")) {
    ##t_reply("404","Not found");
    ##  exit;
    ##}


}
```

Using this config file i am able to connect my soft phones, i can make calls as well. But when the call is initiated it is printing the below logs. what am i doing wrong?

```
new branch at sip:user5@192.168.0.245:43249;transport=udp
Sep  3 12:10:41 [1475] ERROR:rtpproxy:force_rtp_proxy: Unable to parse body
incoming reply
incoming reply
ACC: transaction answered: timestamp=1409726454;method=INVITE;from_tag=467f1820;to_tag=3361724647;call_id=MDE2ZDExYTIyYmEzMGVkZGNhZGIwMzM2NDhjYTcwODk.;code=200;reason=OK
incoming reply
ACC: transaction answered: timestamp=1409726476;method=BYE;from_tag=3361724647;to_tag=467f1820;call_id=MDE2ZDExYTIyYmEzMGVkZGNhZGIwMzM2NDhjYTcwODk.;code=200;reason=OK
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've called *engage_rtp_proxy()* or *rtpproxy_offer()* on requests without a SDP body.

To prevent this, you should use the following conditional on your rtpproxy code:

```
if (has_body("application/sdp")) {
    ... rtpproxy stuff ...
}
```